# Tkinter Optionmenu-options list to be update(Upon selection, should remove that selection from options)

Tags: python, tkinter

Option Menu has 3 choices **"a","b","c"**.Suppose user selects "b" for the first optionMenu. When he click on the add button, the 2nd optionMenu should only display two options **"a","c"** because he has already selected option **"b"**

My code is displaying the three options irrespective of the option/choice selected. Is there any way out for this

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master=master
        self.func()

def func(self):
    self.count=0
    self.op_row=0
    button=Button(self.master,text="Add",command= self.func_op)
    button.grid(column=0,row=0)
    label=Label(self,text="Welcome")
    label.grid(column=0,row=0)

    def func_op(self):
        self.count=self.count+1
        self.op_row=self.op_row+1
        self.var=StringVar()
        options=["a","b","c"]
        op=OptionMenu(self.master,self.var,*options)
        op.grid(column=0,row=self.op_row)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    aplication = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How is the user going to know what they selected, if you remove the value they selected? This sounds like it would be very confusing to the use to pick a value and see that value vanish.

Comment: When I have selected an option and the drop down displayes that option. After then i have a add button that adds one more option menu and for that i want that the options should appear as ['b', 'c'] because i have already selected a

Comment: From a usability standpoint it sounds like you should be using a regular menu rather than an option menu. An option menu is designed to select one value, and show you the selected value. If you have no need to show the selected value, there's no need to use an optionmenu.

Comment: Will you please show me an example. As far as I know, regular menu cannot solve this issue

Comment: I don't know enough about what your app is supposed to do to give a good answer, and attempting to do so in a comment would be pointless. An option menu is just a menubutton and a menu, so of course it can solve this. You just don't need the extra behavior of the OptionMenu. What you need depends on a lot of factors. Are you really picking between the letters a, b and c? is the list of items to pick really only three items long? What happens when they pick something from the list, do you really only want to remove it without doing anything else? And so on...

Comment: Okay. Let me put it like this. I am making this UI where user can select options from a fixed list. Suppose for the 1st option menu, he selected **b** so when he clicks the add button, he can only see remaining 2 options as **b** is already selected. Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Now the `Name` menu has 3 element `a,b,c` and if the `button` is pressed the chosen one will be "added" (printed to the console) and will disappear from the list.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    import tkinter as tk
else:
    import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.dict = ['a','b','c']
        self.variable_a = tk.StringVar()
        self.optionmenu_a = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_a, *self.dict)
        tk.Button(self, text="Add", command=self.func).pack()
        self.optionmenu_a.pack()
        self.pack()

    def func(self):
        menu = self.optionmenu_a["menu"]
        print self.variable_a.get() + " added"
        menu.delete(self.dict.index(self.variable_a.get()))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

You cant delete the last element as far as i know. But if you delete the last element you can just delete the whole options menu.

EDIT: Edited according to OPs comment, and edited the code

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am looking for something different. I am making this UI where user can select options from a fixed list. Suppose for the 1st option menu, he selected b so when he clicks the add button, he can only see remaining 2 options as b is already selected. Is there any way to do this

Comment: Thanks! But its still not that What I want. I have edited my question

Comment: Okey, i give up, and i am flagging your question. Next time take some time and ask your question directly.

Answer (score 2):

The optionmenu isn't designed to have elements removed when they are selected. It's specifically designed to *display* the item that was selected.

If you want to let the user pick something from a menu and then remove the item from the menu, you should just use a menubutton and a menu. That is exactly what an OptionMenu is, except that it has additional behavior that you explicitly don't want to use.

Here's a simple example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.menubutton = tk.Menubutton(self, text="Pick an option", indicatoron=True, 
                                        borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self.menubutton, tearoff=False)
        self.menubutton.configure(menu=self.menu)
        for choice in ("a", "b", "c"):
            self.menu.add_command(label=choice, 
                                  command=lambda option=choice: self.set_option(option))

        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.menubutton.pack(side="top")
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def set_option(self, option):
        self.text.insert("end", "you have chosen %s\n" % option)
        self.menu.delete(option)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Your users might find it very strange and confusing to see items disappear from a menu. It your main goal is to simply prevent the user from picking the same option twice you can simply disable the item once it is chose with something like this in place of the delete statement:

```
self.menu.entryconfigure(option, state="disabled")
```